# What will happen if I do not follow publisher(IEEE/Springer) format for one page?

Tags: publications, research-process, conference, formatting, ieee

One conference has accepted my paper, but I'm unable to follow publisher format for one page, I have to change some margins for this page.

Actually I've to insert a table and table is slightly bigger in size so I have to change margins and I've tried almost all the possible ways to fit it in that page and I've only one page I can't use more space/page.

If I do this, will they reject my final submitted copy of paper? What will be the effect of this in the printed copy?

Comment: Change your table!

Comment: @ShakeBaby any other solution?

Comment: Talk to the editor. There is no answer we can give that is more authoritative than that will be.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the typesetter will fix the margins, etc. when it's published. Otherwise, could you slightly reduce the font to make the overall table smaller?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Using a smaller font in tables is common and perfectly acceptable; changing the margins is usually not.

Comment: IEEE conference papers are not typeset separately and it is the author's responsibility to follow the templates.

Answer (score 1):

IEEE has a web-based tool to check if the camera-ready version complies with the format. You are allowed to submitted 3 times (I don't know what happen if you fail 3 times). If the tool says OK, then it is OK, I don't think any human can recognize a small change in the margin of 1 page.

For Springer, I don't recall they have any similar tool. I think if your changes are not recognizable by human eye then it is OK.

Comment: If your paper fails the check three times, you can just create a new instance named slightly different and try again. It has never been an issue in all the years I have been using the checker.

Comment: Springer has an offshore team of typesetters that try to fix some things based upon the .tex files submitted by the author - and thereby sometimes break others, make sure to check the version they send you.

Comment: @o4tlulz I just submitted a camera-ready version of a paper, it seems they allow 10 times now.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities which depend on what sort of conference you are submitting to.

- Usually well-known and flagship conferences require submission of
  either the .doc or .docx file for conversion to a compatible pdf file
  to pdfexpress (The IEEE pdf checking tool). You can also generate
  your own pdf and submit it for checking. In this case, conferences
  provide you with a password that you need to use when preparing the
  submission, and the tool actually checks for correct margins.
- Smaller conferences might have someone checking the files manually so
  it is quite possible that they will not notice it, especially if it 
  just only larger than the actual margins. So you can get away with it.

Having said that, it is for the best to follow the templates and submission requirements. It is not uncommon for conferences to add page numbers and copyright information to the pdf at which point you might end up with text over other text and a bit of a messy situation.